# Different/separate session frontend and backend

Tags: php, session, authentication, frontend, backend

Firstly, my English is not too good.

Hi, I have problem with my project

I created a website that allows you to login from frontend (as member) and as admin.
I login to both (frontend and backend) using a different username and password but once I logout from the backend, the frontend will logout too.

I think this is because I run the `session_destroy()` script, and it destroys all sessions including the frontend session.

I have tried to search for this using `Zend Framework` and `Joomla` with `PHP`

Comment: Are you creating session variables for these..??

Comment: Using different session names should solve this.

Comment: @Gumbo : or different session store path on frontend and backed

Comment: yes, i do
i create different session name for both as well

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating different variables for different sessions..

Here are some of the examples which may get handy in case..

```
<?php 
 // you have to open the session to be able to modify or remove it 
 session_start(); 

 // to change a variable, just overwrite it 
 $_SESSION['size']='large'; 

 //you can remove a single variable in the session 
 unset($_SESSION['shape']); 

 // or this would remove all the variables in the session, but not the session itself 
 session_unset(); 

 // this would destroy the session variables 
 session_destroy(); 
 ?>
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Hi thank you for answer, 
is it possible to use only session_unset ?

Comment: You can use `session_unset` but only when you are using multiple session variables.. this will unset all the variables...

Comment: so i can change the logout script
my logout script now is 
session_start(); session_destroy();

i will change it to
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['username']);
unset($_SESSION['password']);

thank you very much Hiren, i will try it now

Comment: Hi Hiren, thank you its working very well, i use unset($_SESSION[something]) with the session role system below

thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is your session when you're logged in as an `admin`:

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = 1;
$_SESSION['user']['group'] = 'admin';
...
```

However, this is your session when you're just a `user`:

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = 99;
```

Wherever your `logout.php` is located, do something similar to this:

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['group'] == 'admin')
    $_SESSION['user']['group'] = null;
else
    destroy_session();
```

I hope you got the idea!

**Update**

This might work:

```
/* Do NOT unset the $_SESSION['user']['role'] */

if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'user') {

    /* For Users */
    $_SESSION['user']['login'] = false;
    $_SESSION['user']['id'] = null;
    $_SESSION['user']['last-visit'] = null;
    $_SESSION['user']['ip'] = null;
}

if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 'admin') {

    /* Unset Admin Specific Variables */
    $_SESSION['admin']['login'] = false;
    $_SESSION['admin']['id'] = null;
    $_SESSION['admin']['last-visit'] = null;
    $_SESSION['admin']['ip'] = null;
}

/* Get rid of session_destroy() */
// session_destroy();
```

By the way, you're just resetting the variables manually, which is somehow equal to destroying the session entirely, but still keeps the session alive for the other side.

**Even Better**

```
/* Assign the `user_id` to the session, when you log in ... */
/* login.php */

$_SESSION[$user_id] = array();

/* Now fill-up the new array with data ... */
$_SESSION[$user_id]['role'] = 'admin';
$_SESSION[$user_id]['login'] = true;

/* When you want to Log out, just simply null the array based on the user_id again */
/* logout.php */

$_SESSION[$user_id] = null;

/* Here you go, as long as you have different user_id in your database, 
   you have separated sessions! */
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answer, 
i did that, i group the user (like admin and user) but if i logout from backend frontend logged out too,

i also try to have a different table for member and for admin, and different session name , but it still not working :(